# How to allow cross-domain requests on ESP8266WebServer

Tags: esp8266, wifi, web-server, raspberrypi

I am using a Raspberry Pi running Chrome (handling the user interface) and connecting via ajax to an Arduino D1 compatible using the IP address as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://10.1.1.100/myfunc?id=5",
        error:  function(jqXHR, exception, response) {
                console.log(exception, response);

        etc...
```

I recently started getting this error (wonder why it didn't happen for the last two years):

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://10.1.1.100/myfunc?n=1. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

I tried various things including setting the browser (Chrome) to `--disable-web-security` and various suggestions, [here](https://hackaday.io/project/12227-smart-home-in-the-iot-way/log/43430-esp8266-direct-access-from-web-app) and [here](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=1085) (and many more) but I can't seem to get it to work. Currently, I have:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handleRoot() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "Root of WebServer!");
}

void setup() {
IPAddress ip(10.1.1.100);
IPAddress gateway(10.1.1.1);
IPAddress subnet(...);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
  }

  server.on("/", handleRoot);

  server.on("/myfunc", [](){    
    String message = "";
    message += "URI: ";
    message += server.uri();
    message += "\nMethod: ";
    message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET)?"GET":"POST";
    message += "\nArguments: ";
    message += server.args();
    message += "\n";
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<server.args(); i++){
      message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
    }
      String num = server.arg(0);

    server.send(200, "text/plain", message);
 });
  server.on("/myfunc", HTTP_OPTIONS, []() {
    server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
    server.send(204);
 });

  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  ...
  server.handleClient();
}


void handleNotFound(){
  String message = "Error!";
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
}
```

So what am I doing wrong? Also, one complication that might crop up later is that the domain from where I am calling this in ajax is https and from what I understand https and http are not compatible with cross-domain requests.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thanx @Majenko but that is too general and doesn't address the esp8266 scenario.

Comment: Does the page that is doing the Ajax request have the CORS headers?

Comment: add the CORS header to every response, not only for 'preflight' OPTIONS request. @Majenko, only resources ncluded from other server need CORS headers

Comment: you don't need the OPTIONS support, just add the ACAO header to the response

Comment: @Juraj and @ dandavis I combined both your comments and it now works!  I removed the OPTIONS part and put server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"); in the response.  Thanx!  If either want to put it in the form of an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: @dandavis - notifying you separately because SE only allows one user to be notified per comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the CORS header to every response, not only for 'preflight' OPTIONS request. The OPTIONS support is optional, but the response returning the 'shared resource' must contain the CORS header

`"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"`

EDIT: since 2020, the library has `server.enableCORS(true);`

Answer (score 4):

just add this line before every response:

`server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Answer (score 4):

```
server.enableCORS(true);
```

The server will add the response `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*` header

Comment: `enableCORS` was added in 2020