# How to allow cross-domain requests with ESP8266WebServer.h ? - CORS policy: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: json, esp8266webserver, security

With an nodeMCUv2 I want:

- to start a wifi server with ESP8266WebServer.h
- serve a root html page which will interact with the ESP and fetch external data

**Issue:**
CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

Tried to make CORS happy, by either one of the followings, but didn't help:

.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

.enableCORS(true);

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
ESP8266WebServer srvAmb(80);
void handleRoot(){
// srvAmb.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   srvAmb.enableCORS(true);
   srvAmb.send(200,"text/html; charset=utf-8", myRootWebPagWithJSExternalFetch);
}
void setup(){
...
    srvAmb.on("/", handleRoot);
...
```

Part of the served root html page:

```
try{
  const Qresponse = await fetch( "https://zenquotes.io/api/random" );
  const Qdata = await Qresponse.json();
  console.log(Qdata);
  ...
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Console log in Chromium:

> Access to fetch at 'https://zenquotes.io/api/random' from origin '192....' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

So, how does one fetch external data from the browser running on PC, smartphone, etc?

Thanks

P.S. One could ask the server to fetch the data, prior to supplying the html page, but that's not esp server's job.

P.P.S. I hadn't the credit to create tag keywords such as:
fetch, CORS, Allow-Origin, policy

REM: under [How to allow cross-domain requests on ESP8266WebServer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/58457/how-to-allow-cross-domain-requests-on-esp8266webserver/91419#91419)

it is suggested that .sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") could be deprecated, very well but ArduinoIDE does not raise any warning; anyway suggested solution fails.

Looking at the source code https://github.com/esp8266/ESPWebServer/blob/master/src/ESP8266WebServer.cpp,
the method sendHeader() on line 238, has a 3rd parameter(a boolean) that if set to true, puts before the passed name & value before the already passed header, otherwise puts it after, aka the declarative order is important.

Viz, what's the valid header the esp server needs to send??
Especially, has Chromium details, states:

> Request URL: zenquotes.io/api/random

> Request Method: GET

> Status Code: 200

> Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

See also: https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin

Comment: One thing, because I struggled with CORS in a different context lately: Are you sure, that your browsers cache doesn't interfere here? I had the issue that setting allow origin to `*` wouldn't help, but as soon as I used a different browser (or in my case a fresh profile of firefox), it was working.

Comment: @chrisl. NO. But I wonder if it has nothething to do with the fact that the fetch is https while the connection with ESP is http.

 GET https://zenquotes.io/api/random net::ERR_FAILED 200

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665232/what-can-cause-chrome-to-give-an-neterr-failed-on-cached-content-against-a-ser

Comment: Details in Chromium: states that the header is missing:
A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because of invalid or missing response headers of the request or the associated preflight request .
...
Request Status Preflight Request (if problematic) Header Problem Invalid Value (if available)
 random blocked  Access-Control-Allow-Origin Missing Header


So it does not do job as Chromium 107 expects.

https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/?utm_source=devtools  and 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 1):

The issue is URL specific.

Indeed, if I change API, namely

```
const Qresponse = await fetch( "https://zenquotes.io/api/random" );
```

by for example:

```
const Qresponse = await fetch( "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/meteofrance?latitude=49.71&longitude=4.16&daily=sunset&timezone=Europe%2FBerlin" );
```

then it works.

I presume that I comes from network developper tools info in Chromium:

> Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

claiming a strict origin for zenquotes.io's API.
My esp server code being:

```
void handleRoot(){
    srvAmb.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*", 1);
    srvAmb.send(200,"text/html; charset=utf-8", myRootWebPagWithJSExternalFetch);
}
```

Remark, with or without the additional 3rd param of sendHeader() it works.